# useRef hook has inconsistent behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application code, I recently faced a weird bug using `useRef` hook, where I needed to conditionally render a component and have an `useImperativeHandle` on it to call some child methods. Across various renders, if I use `myRef.current.<function>` it works fine, but if I use `const c = myRef.current` and then later use `c.<function>` it did not worked as `c` was undefined. Take a look at this example I came up with to replicate this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-thunder-y1ft0?file=/src/index.js:115-313 (Could not add snippet here because SO doesn't support JSX yet)

EDIT: A better example - https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-stonebraker-gd7gq?file=/src/App.js

With `WorksFine` component mounted, run the code and see the console.
Now comment out `WorksFine` and uncomment `DoesNotWorkFine` and see what happens. I hope this would make it clear what I'm asking.

I was under the impression that `useRef` returns an object whose `current` property can be mutated and would be accessible in all "past" or future renders. What am I missing here?

Comment: First issue: useEffect closure in whish you grabbed the refs value and never asked for the current one. Second: I think it is garbage collector  (may be react's ? ) issue; I added a logger to log when the componentA got unmounted, but still the function exists in memory and is executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was under the impression that useRef returns an object whose current property can be mutated and would be accessible in all "past" or future renders.

Yup that's right, the issue with the `DoesNotWorkFine` component is that it has a reference to the *content* of the container, not the container itself.

In case it's helpful to reiterate, you can think of the object that comes out of `useRef` as a container, and the `.current` property is the content of that container.

```js
// myRef is the container
const myRef = useRef(null);

// the "ref" variable below is not actually a ref as defined by React, it's the content
// inside the ref because it's pulling the `.current` property off the actual ref
const ref = myRef.current;
```

You can reach into the container at any time and the content you grab from it will be up to date. But if you pull out the content, then the thing inside the container can change while you're still holding onto the old content.

Comment: You're right. I don't know how I missed this, should probably sleep lol